# symfony controller class not found

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to symfony and maybe I am missing something really simple but I am not able to spot it. Any help will be much appreciated. I have these two files:

C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\src\Apps01\ResourceCalBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml

```
ResourceCalendar_Login:
    pattern:   /resourcecalendar/login
    defaults:  { _controller: AppsRollerResourceCalBundle:Login:DisplayLogin }
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony\src\Apps01\ResourceCalBundle\Controller\LoginController.php

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LoginController
{
public function DisplayLoginAction()
{
    return new Response('<html><body>Hello There!</body></html>');
}
}
```

Yet when I point my browser to http://example.com/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/resourcecalendar/login I get the following error:

```
 The autoloader expected class "Apps01\ResourceCalBundle\Controller\LoginController" to be defined in file "C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony/src/\Apps01\ResourceCalBundle\Controller\LoginController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
 500 Internal Server Error - RuntimeException
```

Can someone point out what I am missing when I can see that the class `LoginController` is definitely there inside the filer?

Thanks
Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first of all you should define a namespace

```
namespace Apps01\ResourceCalBundle\Controller;
```

as your error told you here:

"namespace probably has a typo."

Comment: Thanks that was it. I tried to go through the documentation but did not catch it.